# How to find URL associated with Google Places API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url, google

Within our enterprise account for Google Cloud services, we are trying to determine what URL is associated with a Google Places API.

Our account is getting billed and we don't know what client to charge as the API key was generated years ago.

The easy solution would be to turn off the API key but we'd like to avoid service interruption.

If anyone has a solution to find out the URL that's firing the API key, that would be very helpful. Google support cannot help us as we do not have a service package with them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to post this on [the channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api+web-services) mentioned in the [support options](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/support#comunity-support) for Places API, so you can get better assistance on this.